# Makefile can't use `conda activate`

Tags: python, makefile, anaconda, conda

I need to activate a conda environment in my makefile in order to run some python scripts, however, whenever I try to run `conda activate env_name`, I get the following message:

> CommandNotFoundError: Your shell has not been properly configured to
>   use 'conda activate'. If your shell is Bash or a Bourne variant,
>   enable conda for the current user with
>
> ```
> $ echo ". /Users/MY_USERNAME/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" >> ~/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> or, for all users, enable conda with
>
> ```
> $ sudo ln -s /Users/MY_USERNAME/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh /etc/profile.d/conda.sh
> ```
>
> The options above will permanently enable the 'conda' command, but
>   they do NOT put conda's base (root) environment on PATH.  To do so,
>   run
>
> ```
> $ conda activate
> ```
>
> in your terminal, or to put the base environment on PATH permanently,
>   run
>
> ```
> $ echo "conda activate" >> ~/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> Previous to conda 4.4, the recommended way to activate conda was to
>   modify PATH in your ~/.bash_profile file.  You should manually remove
>   the line that looks like
>
> ```
> export PATH="/Users/MY_USERNAME/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
> ```
>
> ^^^ The above line should NO LONGER be in your ~/.bash_profile file!
>   ^^^

I've tried changing the shell for the makefile by adding `SHELL := /bin/zsh` at the top, but this doesn't fix the problem. Additionally, I need this makefile to be able to run using whatever the default shell is for the computer (some of my teammates use zsh, others use bash). It seems like no matter what I do, I can't get `conda activate` to work in the makefile.

What can I do to get it to work, or is this impossible?

Comment: This problem is killing me. Tried everything but nothing works. :/

Answer (score 34):

After a bit of searching around, I came up with adding this pattern to my Makefile to make `conda activate` work.  Others may be able to simplify.

```
# Need to specify bash in order for conda activate to work.
SHELL=/bin/bash
# Note that the extra activate is needed to ensure that the activate floats env to the front of PATH
CONDA_ACTIVATE=source $$(conda info --base)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh ; conda activate ; conda activate

py3build:
    ($(CONDA_ACTIVATE) py3.6 ; python setup.py build )
```

Comment: Note that this was with conda version 4.6.11

Comment: To which file are you adding this? to ur baschrc? If not where is the Makefile  location? Is this on linux?

Comment: Added to a Makefile in a project containing the setup.py file.  I use MacOS High Sierra.

Comment: This stopped working for me in conda 23.5.2

Answer (score 10):

You should use `.ONESHELL:` directive at beginning of script. This run all in the same shell.

Answer (score 8):

Wonderful solution by [@Traveler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/541202/traveler). But keeping in mind the suggestions by both [@Felipe Maza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12557375/felipe-maza) & [@Tomasz Bartkowiak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8741356/tomasz-bartkowiak), adding `.ONESHELL:` before the recipe solves all the errors.

I use a Linux system with `zsh` as my shell and the current latest `conda` version: 4.12.0

Therefore, the recipe will be:

```
.ONESHELL:

SHELL = /bin/zsh
CONDA_ACTIVATE = source $$(conda info --base)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh ; conda activate ; conda activate

# Create conda env from env.yml and compile and install exact pip packages
conda-pip:
    conda env update --prune -f env.yml
    $(CONDA_ACTIVATE) <<env_name>>
    pip-compile requirements/req.in
    pip-sync requirements/req.txt
```

`conda-pip` does the following:

1. Create a conda environment based on an `env.yml` created beforehand.
2. Activate the conda environment by replacing `<<env_name>>` with the environment name that is set in the `env.yml`.
3. Use `pip-compile` and `pip-sync` to compile and install exact pip packages to the conda environment.

> Note: You still need to **activate** the conda environment to use it in the terminal after this because `conda-pip` started and ended in a separate sub-shell.

You can check more about `pip-compile` and `pip-sync` here: [pip-tools](https://github.com/jazzband/pip-tools)

Answer (score 3):

One important thing you need to remember is that `Makefile` will execute each line of the recipe in a separate sub-shell so e.g. exporting `PATH` in one line will not affect what the command in the next `Makefile` line can see! Please refer to the [Makefile manual - Recipe Execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Execution.html#Execution):

> *When it is time to execute recipes to update a target, they are executed by invoking a new sub-shell for each line of the recipe, unless the `.ONESHELL` special target is in effect (see Using One Shell) (In practice, make may take shortcuts that do not affect the results.)*
>
> *Please note: this implies that **setting shell variables and invoking shell commands such as cd that set a context local to each process will not affect the following lines in the recipe**.*

Answer (score 2):

This is also a minimal working solution in `bash`. I have tested this one in Ubuntu.

Note that use of `.ONESHELL:` is actually mandatory. If you ignore that flag, every command in the shell would be executed in a separate shell. In that case you would need to append all you scripts with a semicolon to make a big one-line command!

```
.ONESHELL:

SHELL = /bin/bash
CONDA_ACTIVATE = source $$(conda info --base)/etc/profile.d/conda.sh ; conda activate ; conda activate

train:
        $(CONDA_ACTIVATE) <<put_your_env_name_here>>
        # other stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

`conda activate` among other things set environment variables. However, `GNU Make` invokes each line of recipe in a newly spawned shell. You would need to invoke `conda activate` in each line of the recipe.

A better way is for makefile to do `conda activate` and then re-run itself in the newly activated environment and only then build your targets.

Comment: But I'm not able to run `conda activate` in the first place. It seems like it's not aware of the shell I'm trying to use, even when I set it beforehand.

Comment: @matt_js Try using the full path to `conda`, .e.g.: `/usr/local/bin/conda activate`.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not where conda is. When I run `which conda` I get this:

`conda () {
 if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]
 then
  $_CONDA_EXE
 else
  \local cmd="$1"
  shift
  case "$cmd" in
   (activate) _conda_activate "$@" ;;
   (deactivate) _conda_deactivate "$@" ;;
   (install | update | uninstall | remove) $_CONDA_EXE "$cmd" "$@" && _conda_reactivate ;;
   (*) $_CONDA_EXE "$cmd" "$@" ;;
  esac
 fi
}`

Comment: It is unfortunate for you indeed that it is a shell function. Which file is it defined in?

Comment: My shell uses `.zshrc`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183959/discussion-between-matt-js-and-maxim-egorushkin).

Comment: Did you solve this? If so your help would be appreciated.